# Using the code to input data for backpropagation

Tags: java, github, neural-network, backpropagation, feed-forward

I am learning to build neural nets and I came across this code on github,

> https://github.com/PavelJunek/back-propagation-java

There is a training set and a validation set required to be used but I don't know where to input the files. The Readme doesn't quite explain how to use the files. How do I test with different csv files I have on this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How so? It tells you exactly what to do. The program needs to get two CSV files: a CSV file containing all the training data and a second CSV file containing all of the validation data.

If you have a look at the Program.java file (in the main method), you'll see that you need to pass both files as arguments with the command line.

Comment: When I run the code, I get this error `Usage: program <training file> <validation file>`

Comment: It can be 3 things: 1) you have not passed 2 arguments (lines 126-129 in Program.java), 2) the program can't make a File object for the training file, 3) the program can't make a File object for the validation file. If you're sure the problem doesn't lie in the first possibility, then you need to make sure that the arguments you're giving to the command line are the paths to the training file and to the validation file because in order to make a File object, Java needs to know where to search for the files...

Comment: Thanks for the help, it was the path that was the problem.

Comment: You're welcome! Have a great learning on neural networks! (For what it's worth, there is a very interesting book for starters on neural networks and deep learning: http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I have read the first chapter but I'm new to python so it was a bit of a challenge understanding the code but understood everything else. I found [brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/wiki/artificial-neural-network/) really helpful too.

Comment: I see, if unfamiliar, there are some strange concepts in python (such as list comprehension etc). Anyway, I wish you all the best in learning the topics!